# Webcrypto: Promise return Permission denied on Edge

Tags: javascript, promise, microsoft-edge, digital-signature, webcrypto-api

I am successfully using the Web Crypto API on Chrome and Firefox. But failed when I test the code using Microsoft Edge. Permission Denied was returned in object Promise. Although I run the simple crypto.subtle.generateKey, it still failed. Please refer to the code below.

```
return window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "jwk", //can be "jwk" (public or private), "spki" (public only), or "pkcs8" (private only)
        {   
            kty: "EC",
            crv: "P-256",
            x: xb64,
            y: yb64,
            d: db64
        },
        {   //these are the algorithm options
            name: "ECDSA",
            namedCurve: "P-256", //can be "P-256", "P-384", or "P-521"
        },
        false, //whether the key is extractable (i.e. can be used in exportKey)
        ["sign"] //"verify" for public key import, "sign" for private key imports
    )
    .then(function(key){           
        return key;
    })
```

Comment: What is the point of the .then. It returns what it gets. A no-op

Comment: I use .then to get key for signature process

Comment: return window.crypto.subtle.sign({
   name : "ECDSA",
   hash : {
    name : "SHA-256"
   }, //can be "SHA-1", "SHA-256", "SHA-384", or "SHA-512"
  }, key, //from generateKey or importKey above //CryptoKey
  convertStringToArrayBufferView(msg) //ArrayBuffer of data you want to sign
  ).then(function(signature) {
   return signature;

  }

Comment: `I use .then to get key for signature process` ... but `.then(function(x) { return x; })` is nothing ... unless you really need that extra "tick" delay (which you don't), it's a no-op, does nothing, redundant

Comment: it's like having a `function noop(x) { return x;}`  ... why would you ever do, say `var x = noop(4)` instead of `var x = 4` - makes zero sense

Comment: yes i need some delay to get the return key. if not i can't get key to execute signature process.

Comment: you must be doing something odd in that case

Answer (score 1):

I try to check the documentation of crypto API.

Where I got the link below.

which shows the support for the method for specific browser in real time.

[Web Cryptography API Live Table](https://diafygi.github.io/webcrypto-examples/)

Below is the output in Edge for ECDSA P-256 method.

[image]

It looks like it is not supported in Edge.

If you open the same page in Chrome then you will see that it is supported.

Comment: It seems ECDSA is not supported at all in Edge. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt801208(v=vs.85).aspx